# How to automatically assign values to aspnetcore controller layer method parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

### Code

#### Web Api Interface

I now have an interface

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICustomSession _session;
    public TestController(ICustomSession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public async Task<CustomResult<string>> Search(TestSearch testSearch)
    {
        return new CustomResult<string>(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

#### My `CustomSession`

```cs
public interface ICustomSession
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

#### My `TestSearch`

```
public class SessionInfo
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class TestSearch: SessionInfo
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

### Problem

`ICustomSession` can only be used in the Controller layer, can not go deep into the business, but the business is the need for `SessionInfo` related information, and `SessionInfo` is actually read from the `ICustomSession`.

Now I need to inherit `SessionInfo` on the parameter class to handle it, but now I don't want to assign the value manually in each api interface

```
testSearch.UserId = _session.UserId;
```

I want to use an automatic assignment method that detects the class that inherits `SessionInfo` and automatically assigns the value from `ICustomSession` to it

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

I want to use an automatic assignment method that detects the class that inherits SessionInfo and automatically assigns the value from ICustomSession to it

Comment: Why not store the data in the appsettings.json and read it by IConfiguration?

Comment: @Rena This is a multi-tenant system and may not pass in one value at a time